# Are there any known issues with jQuery-UI between IE9 and IE10?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, jquery-autocomplete

I've got IE10 on my computer at work, and I'm developing an application which I've just added jQuery Autocomplete to.  When I run it from Visual Studio 2012, it runs fine.  When I publish it to our server and run it using our Intranet address, it runs fine.  However, it has stopped working for all of my users.  I can't, for the life of me, figure out why.

I'm not asking for anyone to debug my issue, but I'm wondering if there are any known compatibility issues that might cause a jQuery control to break a program running on IE9 while allowing it to run on IE10.

Comment: I had the same problem with IE11 when our company decided to upgrade without doing any testing.  Next thing you know all my applications had issues with Ajax and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in your head of your page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

This should make the browser emulate and fall back to IE8 mode.

Comment: This helped a lot, actually!  When I set IE equal to 8 or 9, it fails to load properly, when I set it equal to 10 it loads fine.  So there's definitely some compatibility issue happening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JQuery compatibility can be viewed here: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Doesn't sound like a compatibility issue based of what's documented there though.